# Angular 2 Typescript app. Compilation error on import. How to specify path from root folder

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I am creating angular 2 application with following structure:

```
app
|--components
|   |--folder1
|   |--folder2
|
|--services
|   |--folder1
|   |--folder2
..............
```

and there are several files in each folder. So when i import service to component, i needed to use something like this

```
import {SomeInfo, SomeInfoService} from './../../services/some/some-data.service';
```

It's the valid way to import service and all is ok. But path is ugly. So i changed path to `app/services/some/some-data.service` and *application works fine*, but i have a typescript compilation error like

```
app/components/some/some-detail.component.ts(3,45): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'app/services/some/some-data.service'.
```

Does anyone have any idea about why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

The Typescript compiler thinks 'app/services/some/some-data.service' is a path below an external module 'app' (in node_modules) and does not see this as a path

```
import {SomeInfo, SomeInfoService} from './../../services/some/some-data.service';
```

Is not that ugly, is it ?

**EDIT**

You can create a (say) `export-services.ts` file in (say) `services` which will group your services

```
export * from './some/some-data.service'
export * from './other/other-data-service'
...
```

Then re-import from that file only

```
 import {DataService, OtherService,...} from './../../services/export-services'
```

Obviously for this to work, you cannot use `default` exports and all your exported component names must be unique

Comment: It does not nice for me. I'll get trouble on moving files or copying import derective to another file. The problem is minor, but maybe there is a more elegant way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find some insights here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039

There are also these discussions as far as code structure goes:
[Issue 5 at coding style guidelines](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-style-guide/issues/5)
[Issue 10 at coding style guidelines](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-style-guide/issues/10)

Cheers,
Raf.
p.s. I would include this as a comment, but I need 50 reputation points for that.